# Shrink Grid to Prevent Overflow of Parent Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a page that's height should never exceed the viewport or have a scrollbar. In that page is a flexbox with a max width and 3 children.

One of the children contains a grid of a elements with an aspect ratio of 1:1. **On smaller screen heights, the grid and it's cells overflow the parent.**

I've been trying to prevent this overflow without changing the aspect ratio of the cells or introducing any kind of scrollbar or hidden overflow. **The preferred functionality would be for the grid and it's cells to shrink to fit the available height of parent flexbox.**

This is for a tile-based game wherein the grid cells are procedurally generated and therefor have a dynamic and inconsistent width & height. For simplicity I've just used a 3 by 4 grid as an example.

Thanks for any help! Below is a Code Pen illustrating the issue.

https://codepen.io/proxygirl/pen/gOjxGJj

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="puzzle">
      <div></div>     
      <div></div>     
      <div></div>     
      <div></div>      
      <div></div>     
      <div></div> 
      <div></div>      
      <div></div>     
      <div></div>    
      <div></div>      
      <div></div>     
      <div></div>                
    </div>  
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 425px;  
  
  background: grey;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.puzzle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.puzzle > * {
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

Comment: Would you allow a JavaScript solution?

Comment: Personally, I don't think that a tile based game should be responsive (as in, the tiles should not resize), because if the game started out with a height of 3 tiles, what happens if the player resizes the viewport mid game? I don't think you would be able to do this with just CSS. Look at something like [this](https://lab.iamrohit.in/eg/?s=VGhlIE1pbmU6IE5vIEpTLCBDU1MgT25seSBBZHZlbnR1cmUgR2FtZSQkJF5eXmh0dHBzOi8vY29kZXBlbi5pby9qY291bHRlcmRlc2lnbi9wZW4vTk9NZUVi) - it is not responsive. Otherwise you would need to look at JavaScript game engines such as PixiJS or Phaser.

Comment: Look at this [here](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2015/02/26/the-basics-of-responsive-html5-games/). You can see the tiles don't change size - only the whitepace around.

Comment: @RichardHenage Of course, any solutions are most welcome!

Comment: @BernardBorg I considered PixiJS but ultimately decided to go with React for this project, not particularly looking to switch approaches as a solution. Perhaps the game itself would be of use in understanding the issue more. [Game](http://45.33.10.115)